# unable to see views in design tab in intellij idea

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, gradle, intellij-idea

Recently I installed new version of intellij idea and i tried to update classpath (in build.gradle :application) to

```
'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
```

after that i can't see or edit any views in design tab. text tab is working completely but design in not working.

unfortunately i cant upload image because of reputation.
but know that the page is only showing me a blanked screen of phone.

1. I tried to return classpath to version 3.4.0 but that did not worked too.
2. I changed style from

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
```

to

```
Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar .
```

that didn't worked too.

I received this message in Render problem from warnings and errors tab:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/Cleaner
    at libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry.registerNativeAllocation_Original(NativeAllocationRegistry.java:130)
    at libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry_Delegate.registerNativeAllocation(NativeAllocationRegistry_Delegate.java:66)
    at libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry.registerNativeAllocation(NativeAllocationRegistry.java:119)
    at android.os.Binder.<init>(Binder.java:404)
    at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub.<init>(IInputMethodClient.java:18)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$1.<init>(InputMethodManager.java:606)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.<init>(InputMethodManager.java:606)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager_Delegate.getInstance(InputMethodManager_Delegate.java:43)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.getInstance(InputMethodManager.java:681)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderAction.setUp(RenderAction.java:245)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderAction.init(RenderAction.java:133)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.init(RenderSessionImpl.java:163)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:383)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:511)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$4(RenderTask.java:640)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.Cleaner PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.android, 10.3.3] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@b45afd8
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:75)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 22 more
```

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-219113) that will be fixed in 2019.2.2 version. Right now you can use Android Studio or the [previous IntelliJ IDEA release](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/previous.html).

Comment: this trick still works in 2023 

Answer (score 1):

they actually tried to fix this issue in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.1 and somehow they did.
but jetbrains technicians made another issue.same error but this time attributes tab can't be loaded.
for now best new version we can use is 2019.2 jbr8